# Configuring NLog using docker container in .NET core API

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

We are experiencing below issue while using NLog in ASP.NET Core Web API along with Docker container. We didn't face any issues in EC2 with IIS Server. Our ECS LaunchType is fargate.

Error:

> Error DatabaseTarget(Name=dbase): Error when writing to database.   >
> Exception:
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

`NLog.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogToConsole="true">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
    </extensions>
    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <target name="dbase" xsi:type="Database"
          dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.ErrorLogDB}">
            <commandtext>INSERT INTO Nlogs(CreatedDateTime,Message,Level,Exception,StackTrace,Logger) VALUES (getutcdate(),@msg,@level,@exception,@stackTrace,@logger)</commandtext>
            <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception}" />
            <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}${newline}" />
            <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbase" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And this is the Docker container file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.21-alpine3.18-amd64 AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
RUN python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install aws-encryption-sdk==1.4.1
RUN python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install cryptography==3.4.8
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
RUN apk add curl
RUN  mkdir -p /opt/datadog
RUN curl -L https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet/releases/download/v2.37.0/datadog-dotnet-apm-2.37.0-musl.tar.gz \
  |  tar xzf - -C /opt/datadog
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.413-alpine3.18-amd64 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProjectWeb.COREAPI/MyProjectWeb.COREAPI.csproj", "MyProjectWeb.COREAPI/"]
COPY ["MyProjectBusinessAccess/MyProjectBusinessAccess.csproj", "MyProjectBusinessAccess/"]
COPY ["MyProjectDataAccess/MyProjectDataAccess.csproj", "MyProjectDataAccess/"]
COPY ["MyProjectEntities/MyProjectEntities.csproj", "MyProjectEntities/"]
COPY ["MyProjectUtility/MyProjectUtility.csproj", "MyProjectUtility/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProjectWeb.COREAPI/MyProjectWeb.COREAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProjectWeb.COREAPI"
RUN dotnet build "MyProjectWeb.COREAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProjectWeb.COREAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN  mkdir -p /opt/datadog
COPY --from=base /opt/datadog .

ENV CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
ENV CORECLR_PROFILER={846F5F1C-F9AE-4B07-969E-05C26BC060D8}
ENV CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH=/opt/datadog/Datadog.Trace.ClrProfiler.Native.so
ENV DD_DOTNET_TRACER_HOME=/opt/datadog

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProjectWeb.COREAPI.dll"]
```

Any help on this is appreciated.